# Selected value from html select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make clicking the battle button print `"You have slain" + selected option + What I have now works for the first option`, but if you select a different option in the dropdown and click battle it still says Fly.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dyph8jh/4/)

```
var mon = document.getElementById('monsters');
var monster =mon.options[mon.selectedIndex].text;

$('#battle').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('dam').innerHTML = "You have hit the " + monster + " for 5 damage";
});
```

Comment: You should use more jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/4dyph8jh/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your solution, you have declared the values of the selected value globally which is set only once during the document load. In order to calculate the right value, you have to declare them locally during the button click.

```
$('#battle').click(function() {
  var mon = document.getElementById('monsters');
  var monster =mon.options[mon.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById('dam').innerHTML = "You have hit the " + monster + " for 5 damage";
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/4dyph8jh/5/

Comment: It's always the simple things i can't figure out. Thank you

Comment: No worries. Everybody miss things at times. Have a great day !!

Comment: Another pair of eyes always helps. Saves you from hours of looking and then going "oh..." Fun question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4dyph8jh/7/)**

Because you're using jQuery it could be simply :

```
$('#battle').click(function() {
    $('#dam').text("You have hit the " + $('#monsters option:selected').text() + " for 5 damage");
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: See another simple mistake, before you updated this I tried $('#battle').click(function() {
    $('#dam').text("You have hit the " + $('#monsters>option:selected').text() + " for 5 damage");
}); and it didnt work haha